# Drawing list of components is slow reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance

I have a list of components (~50-100), these components are quite advanced; they contain a lot of child elements that obviously takes some effort to be drawn out.

The result is that the UI "freezes" 1-2 seconds when navigating to the page, it actually freezes before getting to the page.

The UI is also a bit laggy when all the components are loaded.

I'm thinking it should be possible to load them in chunks in some way? Or only draw the full component out if it's visible on the screen somehow, and have a skeleton component when it's not in the viewport.

What is the recommended approach here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must avoid useless renders with memo.

Be careful not to call APIs for no reason.

Also you should use useCallback and useMemo to avoid call methods which return same value for children components.

Context API is a good option to avoid Drilling states as props to nested components.

You could use lazy loading to render children components along with scroll as well.

Comment: Just to clarify: I’m not doing any API calls on the said page, so no need to think about data fetching. I came across this library that might solve the issue: https://github.com/roderickhsiao/react-in-viewport, thoughts on that?

Comment: You can use this library to figure out your problems in your components:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/react.
And for lazy loading you can use this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload

Comment: Thanks! react-lazyload was exactly what I was looking for.